# Android - How to get file by file name?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file, path

I have the path of an image, that was selected from Gallery, stored in `sqlite` :

> /emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg

The user has moved the image to another directory, so the new path is :

> /emulated/0/DCIM/NewDirectory/image.jpg

Is there a way for me to find the new path of the image?

Can i get the path of a file if i have the file name(image.jpg) and if so, what happens if there a multiple files with the name image.jpg on the phone?

Comment: `Is there a way for me to find the new path of the image?` I doubt but No, unless you injected something on that image so that you can identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, Yes.

If you know anything unique about the file (besides its name, which could also have changed) then using `getContentResolver().query(...)` or [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) will probably be your best bet to search it out.

If it is an image you have inserted yourself then you can easily add something unique to the file information to make locating it later easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot do that. Because if user want to change it, you have to find that file on storage.

Besides, you can use MD5 to get that signature of file, save it, then you can use later to find exactly what truly file is.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid way to traverse all the pictures, check the match by saving the hash code and md5 code.Do not know what method can be obtained through the original path after moving the image path.